# Can X-rays emitted due to bremsstrahlung radiation have frequency matching with other EM waves like visible ones?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

The continuous X-ray spectrum has x-rays of widely varying frequencies. Since an E-M wave is characterized by its frequency, is it possible for the X-rays coming out of heavy metals due to bremsstrahlung radiation to have the frequency matching with other light waves like visible ones, radio waves, or others?
In short, while producing X-rays, can we produce other types of EM radiation?

Comment: *By definition*, X-rays cannot be visible light or radio waves, so this really doesn't make sense to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The continuous X-ray spectrum comes from [Bremsstrahlung radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung), which is the radiation emitted whenever an electric charge is accelerated or decelerated. In this case electrons striking the metal are decelerated by collisions with metal atoms and emit EM radiation as a result. The spectrum is continuous because the electrons experience a range of different decelerations - some electrons will be strongly decelerated and emit high energy X-rays while some will be weakly decelerated and emit lower energy X-rays.

Light and radio waves are just electromagnetic waves, like X-rays, and in principle they too will be emitted. However in practice the intensity of the radiation emitted at optical or radio wavelengths is vanishingly small.

But light and radio waves are indeed emitted by accelerating charges in other contexts. For example a filament light bulb emits light because electrons are accelerated by thermal vibrations. This too produces a continuous range of frequencies, which is called back body radiation.

Radio waves are emitted when we accelerate electrons using an oscillating voltage. A radio transmitter applies an oscillating voltage to its aerial and that accelerates electrons in the aerial and produces radio waves as a result.

Comment: Weakly decelerated electrons can emit radiations having wavelength in order of $100nm$. So shouldn't such radiations be called  visible light instead of X-rays because X-rays have wavelength in order of $0.1nm$

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of an EM wave as it interacts with matter is frequency dependent. X-rays have high frequencies and show greater penetrability in matter as compared to visible light of lower frequency. If the frequency of EM wave coming out of any source has that of visible light they would not be X rays but visible light.